# Div tag positioning with css

Tags: html, css

I want to keep fixed the "heading"class while I scroll down in the "description" class.but when I add "position:fixed;" in css the heading class gets small.How can I overcome this problem?

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.mainHeader {
  background: #aea5af;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-bottom: 10px dotted black;
}

.mainArea {
  max-width: 1180px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.mainArea:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.mainHeader:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.logoArea {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
}

.headerRightArea {
  float: right;
  width: 70%;
  text-align: right;
}

input {
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #fff200;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.oneHalf {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  overflow: scroll;
  display: block;
  height: 400px;
}

.scrollbox {
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.bg_image {
  background: #34675C;
  height: 800px;
  padding: 30px 30px;
}

.heading {
  display: block;
  background: #6AB187;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 45px;
  position: static;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.description {
  color: #021C1E;
  font-size: 29px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

#tt {
  text-align: center;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Class 6</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="all" />
</head>

<body>
  <!--Header Area Start-->
  <header class="mainHeader">
    <div class="mainArea">
      <div class="logoArea">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="CN_Logo.png" alt="CN_Logo.png" height="100px" width="200px" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="headerRightArea">
        <form action="#">
          <input type="text" placeholder="User Name" name="user" />
          <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" />
          <input type="submit" value="Sign In" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <!--Header Area End-->
  <!--Section Area Start-->


  <section class="bg_image">
    <div class="mainArea">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="oneHalf">
          <div class="scrollbox">
            <div class="heading">
              Hello, Cartoon Fans
            </div>
            <div class="description">
              Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television
              channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the
              Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was
              launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is
              an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television
              channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the
              Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was
              launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is
              an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television
              channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the
              Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was
              launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is
              an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television
              channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the
              Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was
              launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is
              an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television
              channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the
              Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was
              launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is
              an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television
              channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the
              Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was
              launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is
              an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television
              channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the
              Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was
              launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is
              an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television
              channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the
              Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was
              launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is
              an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television
              channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the
              Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was
              launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is
              an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television
              channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the
              Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was
              launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is
              an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television
              channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the
              Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was
              launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is
              an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television
              channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the
              Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was
              launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is
              an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television
              channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the
              Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was
              launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is
              an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television
              channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the
              Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was
              launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is
              an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television
              channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the
              Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was
              launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is
              an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television
              channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the
              Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was
              launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is
              an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television
              channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the
              Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was
              launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is
              an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television
              channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the
              Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was
              launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is
              an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television
              channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the
              Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was
              launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is
              an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television
              channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the
              Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was
              launched on October 1, 1992.Cartoon Network is an American basic cable and satellite television channel that is owned by Time Warner through the Turner Broadcasting System subsidiary. It was launched on October 1, 1992.
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="lastHalf">
          <div class="center">
            <img id="tt" src="cartoon_network.jpg" alt="cartoon_network.jpg" id="section_right" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```